# creating blur and differentiated margin using hover in html and css

Tags: html, css, button, hover

hello i was trying to create the hover effect of the left hand side buttons of this website http://esya.iiitd.edu.in/# but was unable to. 
The effect is basically a margin shift of the text and unevening of margins which i am unable to acheive using any code knowledge that i have ( which is very little )

```
<style>
#button { 
\properties of button/
}
#button:hover {
\code that i am not able to write/
}
```

also is this acheivable only using css or can i use javascript ( not jquery ) also ?

Answer (score 0):

This is totally doable with pure css as long as you use a plain image with the `img` tag inside your button

HTML example:

```
<a id="#button" href="someurl"><img src="someimage.jpg" /></a>
```

Then use this CSS

```
#button {
transition: margin-left 1s;
margin-left: 0px;
}

#button:hover {
margin-left: 50px;
}

#button:hover img {
        filter: blur(5px);
        -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
        -moz-filter: blur(5px);
        -o-filter: blur(5px);
        -ms-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Note that you can change the blur parameter (here `5px` to adjust the blur effect)
If you want to add text over the image.
Place a SOMETEXT after the `img` tag and before the colsing `a` tag, and use `position: relative` to positionate it correctly.